# No columns to parse from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have looked through several of the solutions linked to this problem and nothing has been able to help me. I do not understand if it is an error with the actual csv file or an error within the code itself. Below is my code: All I get is `No columns to parse from file`. Nothing more nothing less.

```
@app.route('/uploader', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.files)
        f= request.files.get('uploadCsv')
        print(f)
        if f is None:
            abort(404)
        if f and allowed_file(f.filename):
            stream = io.StringIO(f.stream.read().decode("UTF8"), newline=None)
            d = ','
            reader = csv.reader(stream, delimiter=d)
            ncol = len(next(reader))  # Read first line and count columns
            print(f"no. of columns: {ncol}")
            if ncol == 2:
                try:
                    print("inside try")
                    df = pd.read_csv(f, delim_whitespace=True)
                    print("file read")
                    print(df.columns[1])
                    df1 = df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: 'ds', df.columns[1]: 'y'})
                    m = Prophet()
                    m.fit(df1)
                    future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=1826)
                    forecast = m.predict(future)
                    fig = m.plot_components(forecast)
                    fig1 = m.plot(forecast)
                    print(fig1)
                    fil1_name = os.path.join(app._static_folder, 'ranj1.png')
                    fig1.savefig(fil1_name, bbox_inches='tight')
                    fil2_name = os.path.join(app._static_folder,'ranj2.png')
                    fig.savefig(fil2_name,bbox_inches='tight')
                    return render_template('images.html' )
                    # return render_template('img.html',title='Forecast', pic='demo.png')
                except Exception as err:
                    print(err)
                    return f"{err}"
            else:
                return f'Only two columns are supported. Columns found: {ncol}'
        else:
            return 'wrong file format'
```

Here is what my CSV looks like -

```
ds,y
10/12/07,9.590761139
11/12/07,8.519590316
12/12/07,8.183676583
13/12/07,8.072467369
14/12/07,7.893572074
15/12/07,7.783640596
16/12/07,8.414052432
17/12/07,8.829226355
18/12/07,8.382518288
19/12/07,8.069655307
20/12/07,7.879291485
21/12/07,7.761744985
22/12/07,7.529406458
23/12/07,8.38526052
24/12/07,8.620110725
25/12/07,7.852439085
26/12/07,7.853993087
27/12/07,8.051978079
28/12/07,7.926602599
29/12/07,7.838343316
30/12/07,9.703144581
31/12/07,9.385972941
01/01/08,8.293799609
02/01/08,8.43468077
03/01/08,8.262042844
04/01/08,8.106816039
05/01/08,7.950149888
06/01/08,9.509259076
07/01/08,8.846784667
08/01/08,8.430545385
09/01/08,8.248267447
10/01/08,8.28172399
11/01/08,8.292798858
12/01/08,8.199189359
13/01/08,9.996522419
14/01/08,10.12707101
15/01/08,8.933796044
16/01/08,8.566173814
17/01/08,8.547722396
18/01/08,8.399760095
19/01/08,8.223090551
20/01/08,8.838986793
21/01/08,10.89720218
22/01/08,9.444938073
23/01/08,8.923324744
24/01/08,8.543445563
25/01/08,8.495560891
26/01/08,8.417372856
27/01/08,8.572627898
28/01/08,8.736489351
29/01/08,8.634086943
30/01/08,8.673512946
01/02/08,8.824236617
02/02/08,8.537975731
03/02/08,9.698061122
04/02/08,12.09745684
05/02/08,10.63527836
06/02/08,9.691716588
07/02/08,9.315600883
08/02/08,8.970813341
09/02/08,8.589141691
10/02/08,8.617400452
11/02/08,8.616314282
12/02/08,8.215547412
13/02/08,8.064950892
14/02/08,8.11342664
15/02/08,7.799343398
16/02/08,7.62754439
17/02/08,7.555905094
18/02/08,7.71154898
19/02/08,7.788626066
20/02/08,7.708410667
21/02/08,7.768533301
22/02/08,7.695303135
23/02/08,7.378383713
24/02/08,7.910590612
25/02/08,7.626570206
26/02/08,7.573531263
27/02/08,7.567862605
29/02/08,7.552237288
02/03/08,7.336936914
05/03/08,8.12474302
06/03/08,7.887584032
07/03/08,7.819636302
08/03/08,7.383989458
09/03/08,7.814399634
10/03/08,7.542213463
11/03/08,7.548555979
12/03/08,7.688913337
13/03/08,7.477038472
14/03/08,7.358830898
15/03/08,7.032624261
16/03/08,7.118016204
17/03/08,7.349873705
18/03/08,7.326465614
19/03/08,7.363913501
20/03/08,7.277938573
21/03/08,7.251344983
22/03/08,7.002155954
23/03/08,7.163946684
24/03/08,7.759187439
25/03/08,7.518607217
26/03/08,7.41397029
27/03/08,7.442492723
28/03/08,7.228388452
29/03/08,6.991176887
30/03/08,7.211556733
31/03/08,7.311218384
01/04/08,7.349230825
02/04/08,7.514254653
03/04/08,7.393263095
04/04/08,7.286191715
05/04/08,7.273092596
06/04/08,7.168579897
07/04/08,7.611347717
08/04/08,7.617759577
09/04/08,7.425953657
10/04/08,8.182000136
11/04/08,7.399398083
12/04/08,7.106606138
13/04/08,7.080867897
14/04/08,7.421177529
15/04/08,7.491645474
16/04/08,7.385851078
17/04/08,7.68294317
18/04/08,7.688913337
19/04/08,7.259116128
20/04/08,8.144969417
21/04/08,8.713910628
22/04/08,8.091015042
23/04/08,7.840312983
24/04/08,7.648739789
25/04/08,8.020927719
26/04/08,7.830028083
27/04/08,7.72753511
28/04/08,7.835974582
29/04/08,7.626570206
30/04/08,7.644440762
01/05/08,7.548555979
02/05/08,7.440733707
03/05/08,7.073269717
04/05/08,7.026426809
05/05/08,7.392031568
06/05/08,7.29301768
07/05/08,7.361375429
08/05/08,7.512617545
09/05/08,7.460490306
10/05/08,7.114769448
11/05/08,7.125283092
12/05/08,7.455876687
13/05/08,7.317212408
14/05/08,7.410347098
15/05/08,7.402451521
16/05/08,7.294377299
17/05/08,6.989335266
18/05/08,6.993015123
19/05/08,7.431299675
20/05/08,7.362010551
21/05/08,7.454719949
22/05/08,7.368339686
23/05/08,7.143617603
24/05/08,6.835184586
25/05/08,6.89060912
26/05/08,6.974478911
27/05/08,7.26612878
28/05/08,7.270312886
29/05/08,7.265429723
30/05/08,7.157735484
31/05/08,6.865891075
03/06/08,7.153833802
04/06/08,7.216709487
05/06/08,7.201916318
06/06/08,7.212294469
07/06/08,7.186144305
08/06/08,6.820016365
09/06/08,6.882437471
10/06/08,7.183111702
11/06/08,7.242797923
12/06/08,7.192934221
13/06/08,7.183870715
14/06/08,6.970730078
15/06/08,6.91770561
16/06/08,7.222566019
17/06/08,7.356918242
18/06/08,7.242797923
19/06/08,7.22329568
20/06/08,7.163172391
21/06/08,7.241366283
22/06/08,6.986566459
23/06/08,6.963189986
24/06/08,7.250635512
25/06/08,7.160845907
26/06/08,7.132497552
27/06/08,7.091742115
28/06/08,7.012115294
29/06/08,6.857514063
30/06/08,6.827629235
02/07/08,7.13009851
03/07/08,7.277247727
04/07/08,7.038783541
05/07/08,6.89060912
06/07/08,6.957497371
07/07/08,7.295735073
08/07/08,7.497207223
09/07/08,7.310550159
10/07/08,7.20489251
11/07/08,7.222566019
12/07/08,7.257707677
01/08/08,7.425953657
02/08/08,7.117205503
03/08/08,7.249925537
04/08/08,8.276903481
05/08/08,7.60638739
06/08/08,7.643961949
07/08/08,8.012349639
08/08/08,7.930206207
09/08/08,7.508787171
10/08/08,7.52131798
11/08/08,7.589841512
12/08/08,7.500529485
13/08/08,7.370230642
14/08/08,7.385230923
15/08/08,7.302496424
16/08/08,7.275172319
17/08/08,7.392031568
18/08/08,7.516977225
19/08/08,7.909122183
20/08/08,7.723120092
21/08/08,7.670428522
22/08/08,7.62900389
23/08/08,7.430707083
24/08/08,7.579678823
25/08/08,7.948385285
26/08/08,7.795646536
27/08/08,8.007367068
28/08/08,7.790696031
29/08/08,7.832807517
30/08/08,7.51479976
31/08/08,7.62754439
01/09/08,7.855157006
02/09/08,7.964850887
03/09/08,7.74586823
04/09/08,8.08085642
05/09/08,8.25997566
06/09/08,7.769800996
07/09/08,8.177515824
08/09/08,9.281730368
09/09/08,8.33854488
10/09/08,7.830425618
11/09/08,7.808729307
12/09/08,7.816819966
13/09/08,7.554858521
14/09/08,8.555066844
15/09/08,8.207946941
16/09/08,8.083637203
17/09/08,7.791109511
18/09/08,7.670894831
19/09/08,7.640123173
20/09/08,7.550135342
21/09/08,8.249313746
22/09/08,8.303999971
23/09/08,8.126813721
24/09/08,7.70616297
25/09/08,7.663877259
26/09/08,7.526717561
27/09/08,7.925880317
28/09/08,7.921535632
29/09/08,8.033982735
30/09/08,7.725771442
01/10/08,7.694392803
02/10/08,7.449498005
03/10/08,7.391415235
04/10/08,7.34601021
05/10/08,8.101374671
06/10/08,8.156510226
07/10/08,7.971085754
08/10/08,7.872836175
09/10/08,7.635303886
10/10/08,7.58781722
11/10/08,7.342131731
12/10/08,8.177515824
13/10/08,8.340933226
14/10/08,8.476579509
15/10/08,7.87359779
16/10/08,7.717351272
17/10/08,7.490529402
18/10/08,7.375882148
19/10/08,8.075582637
20/10/08,8.165363632
23/10/08,7.585281079
24/10/08,7.607381426
25/10/08,7.267525428
26/10/08,8.040124664
27/10/08,8.109224953
28/10/08,8.806873267
29/10/08,7.747164967
30/10/08,7.480992163
31/10/08,7.346655163
01/11/08,7.247080585
02/11/08,7.938088727
03/11/08,9.035629778
04/11/08,8.041091004
05/11/08,7.406103381
06/11/08,7.973844376
07/11/08,7.768110379
08/11/08,7.471363088
09/11/08,8.030084094
10/11/08,8.729397123
11/11/08,7.93701749
12/11/08,7.665284718
13/11/08,7.580189418
14/11/08,7.710653324
15/11/08,7.261225092
16/11/08,8.046549357
17/11/08,8.093462275
18/11/08,7.767263997
19/11/08,7.496652438
20/11/08,7.552237288
21/11/08,7.497207223
22/11/08,7.312553498
23/11/08,7.938802248
24/11/08,9.058703197
25/11/08,8.194229305
26/11/08,7.519149958
27/11/08,7.551186867
28/11/08,7.713784617
29/11/08,7.605890001
30/11/08,8.499029221
01/12/08,8.291797105
02/12/08,7.89469085
03/12/08,7.790282381
04/12/08,7.655390645
05/12/08,7.610357618
06/12/08,7.531016332
07/12/08,8.231376046
08/12/08,8.006700845
09/12/08,7.858640656
10/12/08,7.697121317
11/12/08,7.595889918
12/12/08,7.73587032
13/12/08,7.351158226
14/12/08,8.031385331
15/12/08,8.394347361
16/12/08,7.823645931
17/12/08,8.08671792
18/12/08,7.77148876
19/12/08,8.688959234
20/12/08,7.747164967
21/12/08,7.960672608
22/12/08,8.624611588
23/12/08,7.996653875
24/12/08,7.620705087
25/12/08,7.431891917
26/12/08,7.462789157
27/12/08,7.448916103
28/12/08,8.251403065
29/12/08,8.555259392
30/12/08,8.315811132
31/12/08,8.309922989
01/01/09,7.758760544
02/01/09,8.808219665
03/01/09,9.121946221
04/01/09,10.15381816
05/01/09,9.267854278
06/01/09,8.434246271
07/01/09,8.137688185
08/01/09,8.04494705
09/01/09,8.228977643
10/01/09,8.141189793
11/01/09,9.215626376
12/01/09,8.732788325
13/01/09,8.510168576
14/01/09,8.104099056
15/01/09,7.950149888
16/01/09,7.852050207
17/01/09,7.656337166
18/01/09,8.044305407
19/01/09,8.801017834
20/01/09,7.829630389
21/01/09,7.777373603
22/01/09,7.93522954
23/01/09,7.672292456
24/01/09,7.38832786
25/01/09,7.511524648
26/01/09,7.663407665
27/01/09,7.789454566
28/01/09,7.807916629
29/01/09,7.824845691
30/01/09,7.906547232
31/01/09,7.70210434
01/02/09,8.477620416
02/02/09,9.149528233
03/02/09,8.062117583
04/02/09,8.06652149
05/02/09,8.059592329
06/02/09,8.049427057
07/02/09,7.762170607
08/02/09,8.097730574
09/02/09,8.018296139
10/02/09,7.616775809
11/02/09,7.842671475
12/02/09,7.768533301
13/02/09,7.530479995
14/02/09,7.332369206
15/02/09,7.224024808
16/02/09,7.416378479
17/02/09,7.427144133
18/02/09,7.397561536
19/02/09,7.495541944
20/02/09,7.399398083
21/02/09,7.008505182
22/02/09,7.118016204
23/02/09,7.483806688
24/02/09,7.571473649
25/02/09,7.648263031
26/02/09,7.474204806
27/02/09,7.472500745
28/02/09,7.211556733
01/03/09,7.343426229
02/03/09,7.482118924
03/03/09,7.410951876
04/03/09,7.403061091
05/03/09,7.452982329
06/03/09,7.423568444
07/03/09,7.085064294
08/03/09,7.210818453
09/03/09,7.356279877
10/03/09,7.304515946
11/03/09,7.46565531
12/03/09,7.869019376
13/03/09,7.248504072
14/03/09,7.07834158
15/03/09,7.221105098
16/03/09,7.33432935
17/03/09,7.292337176
18/03/09,7.299121463
19/03/09,7.283448229
20/03/09,7.301822342
21/03/09,7.062191632
22/03/09,7.181591945
23/03/09,7.505492275
24/03/09,7.874739125
25/03/09,7.578656851
26/03/09,7.36707706
27/03/09,7.257002707
28/03/09,7.056175284
29/03/09,7.502738211
30/03/09,7.443078374
31/03/09,7.481555702
01/04/09,7.482118924
02/04/09,7.519149958
03/04/09,7.659642955
04/04/09,7.244227516
05/04/09,7.232733136
06/04/09,7.342131731
07/04/09,7.421177529
08/04/09,7.492203043
09/04/09,7.31521839
10/04/09,7.141245122
11/04/09,7.009408933
12/04/09,7.087573706
13/04/09,7.304515946
14/04/09,7.374629015
15/04/09,7.512617545
16/04/09,7.517520851
17/04/09,7.374001859
18/04/09,7.141245122
19/04/09,7.161622003
20/04/09,7.484930283
21/04/09,7.512617545
22/04/09,7.444833274
23/04/09,7.474204806
24/04/09,7.671826798
25/04/09,7.842278779
26/04/09,7.924072325
27/04/09,7.828436359
28/04/09,7.586803535
29/04/09,7.629975707
30/04/09,7.709756864
01/05/09,7.526717561
02/05/09,7.193685818
03/05/09,7.257707677
04/05/09,7.454141078
05/05/09,7.481555702
06/05/09,7.559038255
07/05/09,7.444833274
08/05/09,7.337587744
09/05/09,7.135687347
10/05/09,7.085064294
11/05/09,7.272398393
12/05/09,7.510977752
13/05/09,7.498869734
14/05/09,7.444248649
15/05/09,7.403061091
16/05/09,6.91671502
17/05/09,6.977281342
18/05/09,7.482681828
19/05/09,7.41397029
20/05/09,7.372118028
21/05/09,7.333676396
22/05/09,7.395107547
23/05/09,7.036148494
24/05/09,6.874198495
25/05/09,6.98471632
26/05/09,7.455876687
27/05/09,7.494986234
28/05/09,7.331060305
29/05/09,7.104965448
30/05/09,6.993932975
31/05/09,6.930494766
01/06/09,7.218176838
02/06/09,7.475905969
03/06/09,7.364547014
04/06/09,7.239932591
05/06/09,7.309212366
06/06/09,7.138867
07/06/09,6.972606251
08/06/09,7.188412736
09/06/09,7.334981879
10/06/09,7.33432935
11/06/09,7.432483808
12/06/09,7.391415235
13/06/09,6.961296046
14/06/09,7.021976423
15/06/09,7.213768308
16/06/09,7.509883061
17/06/09,7.328437353
18/06/09,7.496652438
19/06/09,7.200424893
20/06/09,7.084226422
21/06/09,7.149131599
22/06/09,7.25629724
23/06/09,7.198183577
24/06/09,7.288927695
25/06/09,7.128495946
26/06/09,7.082548569
27/06/09,6.822197391
28/06/09,6.947937069
29/06/09,7.112327445
30/06/09,7.199678346
01/07/09,7.317212408
```

Comment: the error is occurring at `df = pd.read_csv(f, delim_whitespace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell for sure, as your code is not runnable. My guess is that
in the line

```
stream = io.StringIO(f.stream.read().decode("UTF8"), newline=None)
```

you are exhausting the `f` buffer, and you cannot read it again. So I would try to either seek it to 0 (maybe `f.stream.seek(0)`?) or to use the `stream` instead of `f` in the `pd.read_csv` call.

Extra:

1. It looks like you are reading the whole thing just to see if it has 2 columns. If that's not an issue, drop the `csv.reader` thing and read with pandas directly.
2. `pd.read_csv(f, delim_whitespace=True)` is not parsing the csv file you posted. Just do `pd.read_csv(f)`.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample snippet code?

Comment: total lines in that csv is just 253. I don't think it is that large